# how to move JTabbedpane down

Tags: java, swing

I want my JTabbedpane on top of panel3 and panel4. Rightnow, JTabbedpane is on top of panel1 and panel2 but I want it on top of panel3 and panel4. I try setBounds to bring JTabbedpane down but it doesn't work. Thanks for everyone help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.Font.BOLD;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER;
import javax.swing.event.*;



public class hotels extends JFrame{

    JButton hotel;
    JLabel image;
     JTabbedPane tabbed,tabbed1;
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel panel1;

    Container pane;
    JPanel panel2;
    JPanel panel3;
    JPanel panel4;
    JLabel departure;
    JLabel from;
    JLabel to;
    JLabel searchflight,searchflight1;
    JButton back, back1;



    public hotels(){


         panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        hotel=new JButton();
        hotel.setText("Hotels");

        Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18);


        hotel.setFont(myFont);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(hotel);

        hotel.setBounds(50, 80, 100, 40);


        image=new JLabel();

        image.setBounds(50,1,80,80);
        image.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));
        image.setBackground(Color.white);
        image.setIcon(new ImageIcon("2.gif"));
        panel.add(image);

       panel1=new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel1.setBounds(0, 30, 300, 400);

        back=new JButton();
        back.setText("<");
        back.setBounds(0, 5, 60, 30);
        panel1.add(back);

        searchflight=new JLabel();
        searchflight.setText("Search Flights");
        searchflight.setBounds(130,5,100,30);
        panel1.add(searchflight);
        tabbed=new JTabbedPane();
   tabbed.add( "Round Trip",panel1);



     panel2=new JPanel();
     panel2.setLayout(null);
     panel2.setBounds(0, 30, 300, 400);
     panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);

     searchflight1=new JLabel();
        searchflight1.setText("Search Flights");
        searchflight1.setBounds(130,5,100,30);
        panel2.add(searchflight1);

      back1=new JButton();
        back1.setText("<");
        back1.setBounds(0, 5, 60, 30);
        panel2.add(back1);


    panel4=new JPanel();
    panel4.setLayout(null);
    panel4.setBackground(Color.white);

     panel4.setBounds(0, 40, 290, 300);
     panel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 10, 10, 10, Color.blue));


     Font f=new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN,12);

       tabbed.add("One Way",panel2);

          panel3=new JPanel();
     panel3.setBounds(0, 40, 290, 300);
    panel3.setLayout(null);

    panel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 10, 10, 10, Color.blue));
    panel3.setBackground(Color.white);

    panel1.add(panel3);

     panel2.add(panel4);


       from=new JLabel();
       from.setBackground(Color.blue);

       panel1.setBackground(Color.blue);



        pane=getContentPane();


          pane.add(panel);


   image.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()

   {

      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
           if (e.getSource()==image){

      pane.removeAll();

      pane.add(tabbed);
      pane.revalidate();
      pane.repaint();


           }


       }


   }


   );

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

 hotels mw=new hotels();
  mw.setVisible(true);
  mw.setSize(300, 400);
  mw.setResizable(false);


    }



    }
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: You could use a `GridLayout` or ` GridBagLayout` to achieve the same result. See [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details